# Hanging a 32 inch TV without snap toggle on plaster

Tags: mounting, plaster, television

I'm looking to hang my tv on a bedroom wall however there is only one stud on that wall. I tried using a snap toggle but behind the plaster, there's concrete that won't allow the snap toggle to fit. The tv is pretty light it's around 15-20 pounds. Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: There are several answers on here that explain how to mount a piece of plywood so it spans two ( or more ) studs and then mount the tv to the plywood. Use the search function.

Comment: I have had mounts for smaller tv’s that only required 1 stud you may look into a different type of stand.

Comment: One stud should be plenty for such a small TV - why is that not an option for you?

Comment: you only need 1 screw into the stud to keep the TV from falling off the wall .... a second screw positioned anywhere would keep the TV from rotating around the first screw

Comment: you can use thumbtacks for that kind of weight. I had rear home theater speakers held up by them, 6 tacks each. The speakers were about 10 lbs each.

Comment: What brand and model TV are you trying to hang?